# KeyError が発生した際、エラーメッセージの一部が欠損してしまう

Tags: python, vscode, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

オブジェクトをキーに持つdictでキーなしエラーが発生したときに、表示されるエラーメッセージが正しく表示されず困っています。

おそらくKeyErrorは `__repr__` を呼び出しているようなのですが、 `__repr__` が戻す文字列に不等号（`<`, `>`）が含まれると、不等号に挟まれた文字列が表示されないようです。
回避策などありましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか？（内蔵ブラウザのせいでしょうか。）

実行環境は、WSL2(Ubuntu)、Python3.8、VSCode+JupyterLab(plug-in)です。

```
!python3 --version
!cat /etc/os-release
!echo


class TestClass():
    message: str

    def __init__(self, message: str):
        self.message = message

    def __repr__(self):
        text = f"aa=<bb> TestClass(message='{self.message}')"
        print('期待値:', text)
        return text


map = {
    TestClass('aa'): 'AA',
    TestClass('bb'): 'BB',
}
_ = map[TestClass('cc')]  # ←キーなしExceptionが発生する。エラーメッセージは、'<bb>'の部分が表示されない。
```

以下、実行結果です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 環境

VSCode 1.77.3
プラグイン: v2023.3.1201040234
IPython : 8.8.0
ipykernel : 6.22.0
ipywidgets : 8.0.6
jupyter_client : 7.4.9
jupyter_core : 5.1.3

Comment: Windows上のPythonインタプリタ単独とかGoogle Colabでは問題無く表示されています。何か使用環境かその中の設定が関係しているのでは？

Comment: 「質問がアバウトすぎる」ということは無いと思いますよ。
ただ、原因は「VSCode+JupyterLab(plug-in)」にありそうですから、それらのバージョン等も書かれた方がよいでしょう。
なお、表示された TraceBack に含まれるコメントの中の `<bb>` も消えていますから、「`__repr__`を呼び出している」といった点は関係が無さそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Google Colabでも問題なく表示できました。

VSCode 1.77.3、
プラグイン: v2023.3.1201040234、
IPython          : 8.8.0、
ipykernel        : 6.22.0、
ipywidgets       : 8.0.6、
jupyter_client   : 7.4.9、
jupyter_core     : 5.1.3

Comment: 2回目ですが、また私のコメントだけ通知もなく勝手に削除されてますね。
私が書いたのは質問者さんが適切な調査や切り分けを行わせるための、「質問がアバウトすぎる」ので、自己解決のための努力をしてほしい旨の発言です。不適切な表現もありません。
にも関わらず私のコメントだけ省いたのでは文脈が読み取れなくなり、質問者さんが私のコメントを無視し、努力の痕跡なく追加コメントしていた事実まで隠蔽していますね。
モデレータの不公平な編集操作には呆れます。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

以下の環境で再現しました。

- Windows 11 + Anaconda
- Python 3.11.3
- Jupyter (server=6.5.4, IPython=8.12.0)
- VSCode 1.77.3

ソースコードは以下の１行のみ。

```py
print('<bb>')) # SyntaxError: unmatched ')'で<bb>が出力できない
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Jupyter単体（ブラウザ上で動作）では再現しないのでVSCodeが怪しいと思って探したら、似たissueが見つかりました。

[Interactive window shows stack trace with bare  tags when running code in unsaved buffer #12532](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12532)

たぶんインタラクティブ ウィンドウ上でのTracback表示に不具合があると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Jupyter単体、WindowsDOS窓からの実行で、正しく動作すること確認できました。デバッグ方法を変えて進めていきます。